# Limits of the sum of two sets, and the sum of two limits of sets.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

If I have two sets $A,B$ such that $A=\bigcap_{n\geqslant1}A_n$ and $B=\bigcap_{n\geqslant1}B_n$ where $A_n\supset A_{n+1}$ and $B_n\supset B_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and if $A_n+B_n=\{a+b:a\in A_n,b\in B_n\}=C$ for all $n\geqslant1$ and some constant bounded set $C$: can I say that $A+B=\bigcap_{n\geqslant1}(A_n+B_n)=C$?  Clearly $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ and $B=\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n$, but can I bring this limit outside?

Comment: Is there a typo in the intersection of the $B_n$ on the first line? Is that supposed to define $B$ (without subscript)?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I've just corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, not always. Let me elaborate.

Choose $A_n = (0,1)$ and then $A_n$ decrease to $(0,1)$, and also choose $B_n = \left\{q_i, n\leq i \right\}$ where $q:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$ is a bijective enumeration of the rational numbers in the interval (0,1). Note that $B_n$ decrease to the empty set.

Now, let's observe that $(0,1)+\left\{q_i, n\leq i \right\}=(0,2)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, where the sum of the sets is immediately included in $(0,2)$ and for any real $x\in (0,2)$ we will be able to write it as $x=z+q$ in infinite ways, where $q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$ and $z\in (0,1)$, so there must exist $i>n$ such that $x=z + q_i$ with $z\in (0,1)$ by cardinality.

However, $(0,1)+\emptyset = \emptyset$ and both expressions do not coincide.

**Remark:** one can also chose $B_n' = B_n \cup \{0\}$ and in that case $B_n'$ decrease to $\{0\}$ and $A_n+B_n'=(0,2)$ but $A+B=(0,1)$ which is a less pathological example; all of this can be proven similarly to what was proved above.

That being said, there is an inclusion which does hold.

Since $A\subseteq A_n$ and $B\subseteq B_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $A+B\subseteq A_n+B_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and then $A+B\subseteq C$.

We can then conclude that $A+B \subseteq C$ but the inclusion may be strict.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The particular case that I require this for is, apparently we can show that $\mathcal{C}+\mathcal{C}'=[-1,1]$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the Cantor set and $\mathcal{C}'=\{-x:x\in\mathcal{C}\}$.  Any tips on showing equality in this case?

Comment: Use that you have a decreasing sequence of *closed* sets $F_n$ that decrease to $\mathcal{C}$ and that if $x\in [-1,1]$ then $x=y_n+z_n$ with $y_n, -z_n\in F_n$ and then work with convergent subsequences to get $x=y+z$ with $y,-z\in \mathcal{C}$ (recall: $y\in \mathcal{C}$ iff $y\in F_n$ for all $n$) to show the difficult inclusion.